# Saving Fragment EditText contents via the main activity FAB button onClickListener

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

I have a tabbed scrolling activity with several fragments as follows:

- com.example.myapp

  - ui.main

    - 1Fragment.kt
    - 2Fragment.kt
  - TabbedActivity.kt
  - DB_Constructors.kt
- res...layout

  - activity_tabbed.xml
  - fragment_1.xml
  - fragment_2.xml

In **activity_tabbed.xml** I have a FAB button:

```java
    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:.../>
```

In **fragment_1.xml**, I have an EditText element:

```java
<EditText android:id="@+id/input_a_fragment_one"
          android:.../>
```

In **fragment_2.xml**, I have an EditText element:

```java
<EditText android:id="@+id/input_b_fragment_two"
          android:.../>
```

I want to write data inputted into both fragments EditText into a Firebase Realtime DB when the fab button is pressed.

In **DB_Constructors.kt** I have created the following class:

```java
class SubmissionDetails(val line1_fragement1: String, line1_fragment2: String)
```

I have undertaken the following in **TabbedActivity.kt**:

```java
class TabbedActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    val ref  = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("userData")
    lateinit var input_a_fragment_one: EditText
    lateinit var input_b_fragment_two: EditText
    lateinit var saveButton: Button
    public val currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser

    val fab: FloatingActionButton = findViewById(R.id.fab)

    fab.setOnClickListener { view ->
        Snackbar.make(view, "A message", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG
             .setAction("Action", null).show()
        saveAccount()
    }
}

fun saveAccount(){

    val userId = currentUser?.uid ?: return

    val submissionDetails = SubmissionDetailsPrep(inputA, inputB)

    ref.child(userId).setValue(submissionDetails).addOnCompleteListener{

        //On Complete Activities...

    }

}
```

in **1Fragment.kt** I have the following:

```java
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        val inputA = input_a_fragment_one.text.toString().trim()
}
```

in **2Fragment.kt** I have the following:

```java
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        val inputB = input_b_fragment_two.text.toString().trim()
}
```

I am aware that certain elements are located incorrectly, but cannot figure out why?  At present, inputA & inputB aren't available in the main TabbedActivity file.  How do I make these available?

Comment: You should post reproducible, compilable code. This code will not compile.

Comment: @Orbit the code won't compile at present.

Comment: Yes, that's what I said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To retrieve the text contents of `input_a_fragment_one` and `input_b_fragment_two` in your `TabbedActivity` `Activity`, perform one of the following:

- Define a listener callback interface which is then implemented by your `Activity`. When the text in the relevant `Fragment` changes, invoke the callback to update a state variable in your `Activity`.
- Retrieve a reference to the relevant `Fragment` by either utilizing a `findFragmentBy*` method, or saving an instance of the `Fragment` during its initialization. You can then interact with the `Fragment` directly to retrieve the text you require.

Other methods exist, but one of these two options will suffice for your purposes.

Comment: thanks.  With the first option - the callback interface would be placed in tabbedActivity?

Comment: @MrT It can be defined anywhere, but should be implemented by your `Activity`.